# Problemas convertendo date para calendar

Tags: java, spring-boot

Tentando converter data de um date para calendar. Usando springBoot. Não tive clareza sobre a verdadeira causa da exceção. Alguém poderia ajudar?

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Boot
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      SpringApplication.run(Boot.class, args);
   }
   @Bean
    public FormattingConversionService mvcConversionService() {
        DefaultFormattingConversionService conversionSeervice = new DefaultFormattingConversionService(true);
        DateFormatterRegistrar registrar = new DateFormatterRegistrar();
        registrar.setFormatter(new DateFormatter("yyyy-MM-dd"));
        registrar.registerFormatters(conversionSeervice);
        return conversionSeervice;

    }
}
```

no Model

```
@DateTimeFormat(tried with and without pattern)
private Calendar releaseDate;
```

no JSP

```
<div>
    <label for="releaseDate">Data de Lançamento</label>
     <form:input path="releaseDate" type="date" id="releaseDate"/>
     <form:errors path="releaseDate"/>
 </div>
```

Exception:

> Failed to convert property value of type java.lang.String to required type java.util.Calendar for property releaseDate; 
>   nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: 
>   Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type 
>   [@org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat java.util.Calendar] 
>   for value 2017-12-06; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
>   Parse attempt failed for value [2017-12-06]

Comment: Como está seu `DateFormatterRegistrar`?

Comment: o que vc quer saber dele?

Comment: Eu quero saber como você converte a data ué.

Comment: não está chegando lá, ele estava sendo sobrescrito pelo Spring. Desabilitei a sobrescrita, mas agora estou com outra exceção

Usei                                                                                                                     
    public static void main(String[] args)
   {
    new SpringApplicationBuilder(Boot.class)
     .initializers((GenericApplicationContext c) -> c.setAllowBeanDefinitionOverriding(false) )
     .run(args);
   }

Comment: porém agora estou com uma outra exceção  org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Invalid bean definition with name 'mvcConversionService' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Cannot register bean definition, o que é lógico porque bloqueei a sobrescrita

Answer (score 0):

Na verdade, o que você está convertendo é de String para Calendar. Por mais que no seu jsp, ele seja type = date, o que chega para o spring é uma String.

Sinceramente não consigo pensar em um uso útil atualmente para a classe Calendar. Acho as classes da API de data do java 8 infinitamente melhores que a Calendar, e aconselho que você aprenda a usá-las.
Ex: java.util.LocalDate

Agora respondendo à sua questão, vou assumir que você está usando Jackson como serializador/deserializador de JSON. Neste caso, crie um deserializador para que o Spring, através do Jackson, consiga converter essa String em um Calendar. Seguem um exemplo de como fazê-lo:

```
public class CalendarDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Calendar> {

    private static final SimpleDateFormat FORMATTER = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

    @Override
    public Calendar deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException {

        String dateAsString = jsonParser.getText();

        Date date = tryParseDate(dateAsString);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(date);
        return calendar;
    }

    private Date tryParseDate(String dateAsString) throws IOException {
        Date date;
        try {
            date = FORMATTER.parse(dateAsString);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            throw new IOException(e);
        }
        return date;
    }

}
```

Aí depois você só precisa indicar que esse seu Deserializer será utilizado para aquela property, anotando lá no seu Model, da seguinte forma:

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = CalendarDeserializer.class)
private Calendar releaseDate;
```

Aí provavelmente vai funcionar.

Comment: não rolou não, por que ai fica habilitado o método carregado pelo boot que contém o starter do web (adicionado no pom) e gera exceção antes de ser possível chegar no conversor.